# Sorting a table column in a grid in extjs after adding multiple records to it

Tags: javascript, ajax, sorting, extjs

I have a grid in my application where i am showing some data in tabular form. Normally when I load a store to it, it will work normally, i mean if we click on the column header, it will sort accordingly. now I am adding multiple records to this table by performing some bulk add operation. That operation is adding the new records at the end and after that if i am sorting the column, its sorting the previous list separately and the new data separately. But if I am adding only one record(that I am doing from different function), it works fine.
code for single add is  :

```
onSingleAdd : function() {
    var rec = Ext.create('kav.model.xyz.xyzmodel', {
        id : null,
        recordid : this.recordid
    });
    this.store.insert(0, rec);
    this.rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);
}
```

For multiple add, I am showing a popup and then hitting a ajax call after that, and on success of that ajax call i am coming back to this page. Code for that ajax call is :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'some/url'
        params : dataToSend,
        scope : this,
        success : function(response, opts){
            var data = eval('('+response.responseText+')');
            if(data.success){
                this.up('window').manager.loadStore();
                this.up('window').close();
            } else {
                //show message
            }
        },
        failure : function(response, opts){
            //handle failure
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your sorting code! That's where I assume your error lies.

Comment: yeah i think so too now,i am using two stores to show data and getting info from both to show in table. will check that again now